# SVG - How do i colour the background of a circle fill pattern

Tags: svg, fill

If I have a circle and I want a pattern with hatched diagonal purple stripes I create the following

```
<circle fill='url(#diagonalHatchPurple)' />

<pattern id="diagonalHatchPurple" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="6" height="6">
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 
             M0,4 l4,-4
             M3,5 l2,-2" 
          style="stroke:purple; stroke-width:2;" />
</pattern>
```

This gives me purple stripes inside the circle on a white background. How do I change the white background to black? I've tried putting 'fill' and 'stroke' in various places within the pattern and path but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

The circle is actually transparent in the white areas so you're seeing the browser's background there.

If you want the pattern to have a black background simply add it in yourself.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill='url(#diagonalHatchPurple)' />

<pattern id="diagonalHatchPurple" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="6" height="6">
    <rect width="6" height="6" fill="black"/>
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 
             M0,4 l4,-4
             M3,5 l2,-2" 
          style="stroke:purple; stroke-width:2;" />
</pattern>
</svg>
```